Is there a need to use double quotes vs no quotes when appending an array in postgresql?
Consider a DB where there is a column tags which is a TEXT[]:
Using double quotes:
UPDATE my_table SET tags = tags || '{"na"}' WHERE name = 'Cat';

Using no quotes:
UPDATE my_table SET tags = tags || '{na}' WHERE name = 'Cat';

Both cases will update a row where name == Cat and append a string "na" to the list of tags. Is there a practical difference between these two methods?

No, there isn't:
SELECT '{na}'::text[] = '{"na"}'::text[];

 ?column? 
══════════
 t
(1 row)

You need the double quotes only as an escape character if the array element contains a {, } or , character.

…and also if it contains whitespace, i.e. '{ na }' <> '{" na "}', and of course also if it contains a quote itself.

For a single element, the curly brackets can be skipped as well, which then works as if the string used both the double quotes and the brackets because array literal syntax no longer applies and the text constant gets appended as-is.

Sorry for that, my comment above only holds up if you cast explicitly like in the answer above, but not if you use an untyped constant like OP does: demo.
